# How to connect google data studio to postgres serverless on AWS using ssh tunnel?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, looker-studio, ssh-tunnel, aws-serverless

I have my database on AWS serverless and I can only connect to it outside the VPC via ssh tunnel, I need to connect from Google Data Studio, does anyone have any solution?

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue? We are having the same

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

To direct connect to PostgreSQL using Data Studio standard connectors, you need a database accessible through the internet.